# system mute of fresh install debian, can't find the audio devices

Tags: debian, audio

The `lspci` command seems not find any audio devices.

```
~$ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0f)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0f)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB xHCI (rev 0f)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0f)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0f)
```

and `alsamixer` is `100`.

Here is the infomation of the audio driver I got from windows driver package:

```
<DriverName>Realtek I2S Audio Codec</DriverName><ClassName>MEDIA</ClassName><Inf>oem20.inf</Inf><HardwareIDs><HID>ACPI\VEN_10EC&DEV_5640 ACPI\10EC5640
*10EC5640 ACPI\10EC5640 10EC5640</HID></HardwareIDs><OS>82</OS><FileName>Realtek I2S Audio Codec.zip</FileName></item><item><DriverName>Intel SST Audio Device (WDM)</DriverName><ClassName>MEDIA</ClassName><Inf>oem10.inf</Inf><HardwareIDs><HID>ACPI\VEN_8086&DEV_0F28&SUBSYS_80867270 ACPI\80860F28
*80860F28 ACPI\80860F28 80860F28</HID></HardwareIDs><OS>82</OS><FileName>Intel SST Audio Device (WDM).zip</FileName></item><item>
```

Following this post, here is some relevant output:

```
~$ lsmod | grep snd
snd_soc_sst_byt_rt5640_mach    12524  0 
snd_soc_rt5640         82914  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         12442  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          147300  2 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_sst_byt_rt5640_mach
snd_compress           17197  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm                88662  2 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core
snd_timer              26614  1 snd_pcm
snd                    65244  4 snd_soc_core,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_compress
soundcore              13026  1 snd
regmap_i2c             12783  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_sst_acpi       12559  0 
i2c_core               46012  8 drm,i915,snd_soc_rt5640,i2c_hid,i2c_designware_platform,regmap_i2c,drm_kms_helper,i2c_algo_bit

~$ cat /proc/asound/cards 
--- no soundcards ---

~$ aplay -L
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
~$ groups |grep audio
lm cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev scanner bluetooth lpadmin
```

### edit `dmesg` output

there are quite a few post on internet about the belowing issue, seems no one found a good answer...

```
 [    3.647103] byt-rt5640 byt-rt5640: ASoC: CPU DAI baytrail-pcm-audio not registered
548 [    3.647132] platform byt-rt5640: Driver byt-rt5640 requests probe deferral   
549 [    3.649476] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1017, idProduct=1006   
550 [    3.649484] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
551 [    3.649689] usb 1-1.1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
552 [    3.649701] usb 1-1.1: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
553 [    3.652310] byt-rt5640 byt-rt5640: ASoC: CPU DAI baytrail-pcm-audio not registered
554 [    3.652338] platform byt-rt5640: Driver byt-rt5640 requests probe deferral   
555 [    3.653581] byt-rt5640 byt-rt5640: ASoC: CPU DAI baytrail-pcm-audio not registered
```

Comment: Does `alsamixer` show any soundcard? Have you tried changing the device using `pavucontrol`? You might need to install it first.

Answer (score 1):

Your audio device is an Intel SST Audio, to get the sound working you need to install the `non-free` firmware [`firmware-intel-sound`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/firmware-intel-sound) from backport:

Add the following line to your `sources.list`

```
# Backports repository
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Update and insatll `firmware-intel-sound`:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-intel-sound
```

Comment: no sound even after reboot

Comment: If lspci still show as in the post, this should mean that the audio card is not working. right?